# What is the unsigned int order in the function struct page* alloc_pages()

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel

`struct page* alloc_pages(gfp_t gfp_mask, unsigned int order)` is the function used to allocate page in kernel. So this will allocate 2^order contiguous physical pages.
So this means the pages will allocate in the manner of 1,2,4,8,16 and so on.
What if only 3 pages are needed or 5 ,9 and so on.

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand023.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alloc_pages` allocates [*continuous page **frames***](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11667/what-is-the-difference-between-a-page-of-memory-and-a-frame-of-memory) from the physical memory. Linux kernel has this ill-named, of course.

I believe it is using the [*buddy allocator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation).

Most of the time you don't even **need** continuous page frames. This is only mostly needed for hardware that does DMA transfers or similar. Very unlikely that you'd need 9 continuous frames. If you really do, you'll allocate 16 pages and free the remaining 7, for example `order=0`.

Comment: free_pages() also take argument of unsigned int order.Therefore, we can not free the remaining 7 pages.

Comment: Yes you can. You'd free just order=1 pages 7 times

Comment: That would be very annoying thing to do. Why the allocation is on the basis of 2^order? Why they didn't take no. of pages directly?

Comment: Because of how the allocator works and how you're supposed to use it

Comment: @MohitVerma I repeat it is very unusual to actually need 9 continuous pages. Why do you think you need them

Comment: I was going through the concept of memory management.So it stuck with me.I thought the slab allocation is used but as you say it uses buddy allocator algorithm. Thanks for clearing the doubts.mate.

Comment: The slab allocator is a frontend to this.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I think you meant order=0, not order=1.

Comment: @IanAbbott indeed :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I don't think you can free partial allocations that way unless you call `split_page()` first. But it is easier to call `alloc_pages_exact()` which effectively does all that for you.

Answer (score 1):

From [the link provided by tkausl](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand023.html):

> The order is the power of two number of pages to allocate

So `alloc_pages(gfp_mask, 3)` will allocate 8 pages.  `alloc_pages(gfp_mask, 4)` will allocate 16 pages, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an exact number of pages, call `alloc_pages_exact()`. It takes the desired size in bytes and the GFP flags, and returns a page-aligned address.  Call `free_pages_exact()` with the same size that was passed to `alloc_pages_exact()` to free the memory.

```
#define MY_BUF_SIZE 20000 /* size in bytes */
```

...

```
        mydev->buf = alloc_pages_exact(MY_BUF_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL);
```

...

```
        if (mydev->buf)
                free_pages_exact(mydev->buf, MY_BUF_SIZE);
```

Note that the implementation of `alloc_pages_exact()` is as follows:

1. Use the specified size in bytes to determine the power of two "page order" for the allocation.
2. Call `alloc_page()` (via `__get_free_pages()`) to allocate a single "compound page" of the determined page order, which consists of a power of two number of single pages.
3. Call `split_page()` to split the compound page into single pages.
4. Call `free_page()` on any unneeded pages at the end of the allocation.

The implementation of `free_pages_exact()` uses the specified size (which ought to match the size passed to `alloc_pages_exact()`) to determine the number of individual pages to free and frees that many contiguous pages (by calling `free_page()`) starting from the specified virtual address.